# What are the current rules for modern pentathlon?

Tags: rules, olympics

The rules for a modern pentathlon competition have changed several times since it was created in 1912, such as combining running and shooting, and an announcement in 2021 that equestrian would be replaced with a different event. Recently, there was the "UIPM 2022 Pentathlon World Cup" in Cairo and there are several more upcoming "UIPM 2022 Pentathlon World Cups" this year. Apparently these are being run on a "new format", and it appears this is the format that will be used at the 2024 Olympics.

What are the rules for modern pentathlon in this series of 2022 world cups? Is the format for the 2024 Olympics set yet, and is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

As of May 2022, the plan is:

- The 2024 Olympics will use the existing rules (i.e. with show jumping)
- The 2028 Olympics will use a different format - although modern pentathlon has been omitted from the provisional list of sports for the 2028 Olympics due to the uncertainty.

The UIPM (the governing body for modern pentathlon) are due to vote on 2nd May 2022 to agree the new format. However, there is significant push-back on the changes from a number of leading athletes so it is by no means clear what is actually going to happen.

Source: [Modern pentathlon: Athletes demand investigation by International Olympic Committee](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/modern-pentathlon/61296363), BBC News